# Uso correcto de this en arrows function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Estoy validando un formulario y me he encontrado que al llamar una función dentro de otra y para por parametro `this` la funcion no retorna el elemento al que hago referencia sino que el objeto `windows`. Para hacer referencia al objeto use `e.target`, sin embargo no he encotrado porque sucede esa eventualidad, espero puedan ayudarme a resolver esta duda. Si es posible usar el `this` o no, en caso de no poder, porque no es posible.

```
//variables
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const asunto = document.getElementById('asunto');
const mensaje = document.getElementById('mensaje');

//funciones
const validarCampo = e => {
  //calcular el tamaño del texto y que no este vacio
  let errores = document.querySelectorAll('error');
  console.log(this);

  validarLogitud(this);
  //validarLogitud(e.target);
  if(e.target.type === 'email'){
    validarEmail(e.target);
  }

  if (email.value !== '' && asunto.value !== '' && mensaje.value !== ''){
    if (errores.length === 0) {
      btnEnviar.disabled = false;
    }
  }
}

//event Listener
const eventListener = function eventListener(){

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initApp );
  email.addEventListener('blur', validarCampo);
  asunto.addEventListener('blur', validarCampo);
  mensaje.addEventListener('blur', validarCampo);
}
eventListener();
```

Answer (score 0):

Al utilizar arrow functión `this` se dirige hacia al padre de la function y no al elemento que la ejecutó, lo correcto es usar `e.target` o bien, sustituir la arrow function por una función normal.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces la forma en como lo he realizado seria la correcta, muchas gracias